# What is the most efficient siege strategy?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

When sieging enemy territory, what strategy is optimal? Is it best to collect all your troops in one huge stack and siege provinces one by one? Or is it more efficient to split into stacks that are as small as possible while still being sufficient to siege at all?

If you have an army that is 10x the garrison, but you are not in a hurry, is it better to siege it normally or to storm?

Answer (score 3):

I supposed we can measure efficiency by two things.
1. Manpower loss
2.Overall siege time.

If your army has a 1 to 10 manpower advantage over a given garrison then assault will result in minimal time and "good enough" losses. If you dont have that manpower advantage its generally inadvisable to assault fort levels > 3. So if you dont have the numbers the second best thing to do is kill all opponent armies and then carpet siege the lands. This will take more time, but it minimizes attrition loss.